# How are all the roots of unity of cyclotomic extension are of this form?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $x \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_n) $ satisfies $x^t =1, t \in \mathbb{N}$. Then show that $x$ is of the form $\zeta_n^k$ for some $k$ where $1 \leq k \leq n-1$  ?

Comment: In a way I want to categorize all the roots of unity in a cyclotomic extension.

Comment: I was going to offer another answer to this question, and then realized that you had not specified what $\zeta_n$ was. Did you mean it to be a primitive $n$-th root of unity?

Comment: Puzzling further over your question, I wonder whether you’re simply asking whether in the field $K_n$generated by the $n$-th roots of unity, these are the *only* roots of unity in $K_n$. Of course this isn’t true, in case $n$ is odd. If $n$ is even, however, it’s true.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you wanted to allow $0\le k\le n-1$. As Lubin pointed out, the claim holds if and only if $n$ is even.

Comment: This is Corollary 3.5.12 in  Henri Cohen's book vol. 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true if $n$ and $t$ are relatively prime. Indeed, if $(\zeta_n^k)^t=1$, then $\zeta_n^{kt}=1$ and therefore $n$ divides $kt$, however, since $n$ and $t$ are relatively prime, $n$ divides $k$, which is absurd.

For example, if $n=4$ and $t=1$, $\zeta_n=i$ but the only root of $x-1=0$ has not the form $\zeta_n^k$ with $1\leq k \leq n-1$.

I think that what you wanted to say is

> Suppose $x \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ satisfies $x^n =1$. Then show that $x$ is of the form $\zeta_n^k$ for some $k$ where $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

In this case the result is true and P Vanchinathan provided an answer for this fact.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that  variable $t$ is free and unrelated to $n$ in the question only after you pointed out.  Then it does not make much sense. Thanks.

Comment: No Sir, the problem is to show that set of all roots of unity arising from $x^t=1$ where t is any positive integer [ or in other words that x is of finite order] belong to the set of nth roots of unity.

Comment: @user229167 But my complain is: Are you fixing $n$ and then you vary $t$ or are you fixing $t$ and then allow $n$ to vary..?

Comment: @Daniel n is fixed and t can vary.

Comment: @user229167 Then it's false. I've shown a counter example.

Comment: Umm, perhaps I might point out that if $n=2$, then $\zeta_n=-1$. I earlier gave you an up-vote, and now I’m not sure I should have.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks! I've edited the answer

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the OP, upon reflection, would allow $0\le k\le n-1$ making your counterexample less interesting. The real question surely is about whether $t$ has to be a factor of $n$. The answer to that is *No, unless $n$ is odd.*

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So we know that the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ contains the element $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$ of order $n$, and the element $x$ of order $t$. We know that $x$ must be of the form $x=e^{2\pi i k/t}$ for some integer $k, 0<k<n,\gcd(k,n)=1$.

Let $\ell=\operatorname{lcm}(t,n)$. A standard exercise in group theory then tells us that we can find integer exponents $a,b$ such that the number $y=x^a\zeta_n^b$ is of order $\ell$ (basically you only need Bezout's identity - ask if you have problems). W.l.o.g. $y=e^{2\pi i/\ell}$ (replace $y$ with its appropriate power to get there).

By basic facts about cyclotomic fields we then know that $[\Bbb{Q}(y):\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(\ell)$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.
But, $y\in K$ and $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=\phi(n)$, so we must have $\phi(\ell)\le\phi(n)$ even though $n\mid \ell$. If $a\mid b$, then $\phi(a)\mid\phi(b)$, so this forces the conclusion $\phi(n)=\phi(\ell)$.

Another basic fact about the function $\phi$ is that if $n$ is a proper divisor of $\ell$ such that $\phi(n)=\phi(\ell)$, then $n$ must be odd
and $\ell=2n$ (think of the way $\phi(n)$ can be calculated using the prime factorization of $n$).

The conclusion is thus that $t$ must be a factor of $n$, if $n$ is even, and a factor of $2n$, if $n$ is odd. In the former case $x=\zeta_n^k$ for some exponent $k$. In the latter case we get the extra possibility that $x=-\zeta_n^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not exactly an issue about cyclotomic extension. If a complex number satisfies $z^t=1$, then you have to show it is of the form $z=\zeta_n^k$. Clear that the equation $X^n-1=0$ has $n$ distinct complex roots. Take $\zeta_n= e^{2\pi i/n}$, and note that all its powers are also roots of the same equation $X^n-1=0$ Now counting them tells that any root has to be among these powers.